# Mudar visibilidade de um INPUT com PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, tenho o seguinte código abaixo, nele uma função JavaScript faz com que quando selecionado certo valor, o display da tag `input`é mudado, deixando ele visível. Também possui um códico PHP, para que, quando o usuário submeter os dados, com alguns dados faltando, ele não perca o que já foi digitado. Porém após o submit, a tag `input` volta a ficar escondida, mesmo estando com o valor OUTRA selecionado, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer com que continue mostrando a tag após o submit com dados faltando?

```
<div class="form-group">                
     <label> Value <br />
       <select class="form-group" name="value" placeholder="<?php $set1 = escape(Input::get('value')); ?>" id="value" onchange="mostraCampo(this.value);">
        <option></option>
        <option value="value1" <?php if ($set1 == "value1") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>value1</option>
        <option value="value2" <?php if ($set1 == "value2") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>value2</option>
        <option value="value3" <?php if ($set1 == "value3") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>value3</option>
        <option value="value4" <?php if ($set1 == "value4") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>value4</option>
        <option value="value5" <?php if ($set1 == "value5") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>value5</option>
        <option value="NENHUMA" <?php if ($set1 == "NENHUMA") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>NENHUMA</option>
        <option value="OUTRA" <?php if ($set1 == "OUTRA") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>>OUTRA</option>
       </select>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="outrainst" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('outrainst')); ?>" id="outrainst" style="display: none;">
    </label>

</div>
```

Esse é o JavaScript para mostrar a tag `input`:

```
    function mostraCampo(obj) {
      var select = document.getElementById('value');
      var txt = document.getElementById("outrainst");
      txt.style.display = (select.value == 'OUTRA' || $set1 == 'OUTRA') 
          ? "block"
          : "none"; 
    }
```

Comment: Quando você retornar a View com os dados faltantes, você recarrega a Página?

Comment: @MatheusCuba eu clico no botão pra dar o submite, ai a tela é recarregada, aparece as mensagens de quais dados estão faltando, e os dados que já tinha sido preenchidos continuam preenchido, porém ele não mostra o `input` mais, só se eu for trocar o valor do `option` e voltar pra OUTRA, ai ele volta a aparecer com o valor preenchido antes, entendeu mais ou menos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você recarrega a página quando retorna os dados faltantes, seu `<select>` volta ao seu estado original, mesmo você marcando ele como selecionado.

O que você pode fazer é simular o evento de `onchange` quando recarregar a página simplesmente usando:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', mostraCampo);
```

Assim, você executa a lógica da sua função sem precisar mudar o campo novamente

**Exemplo:**

No exemplo abaixo, note que ao carregar a pagina, mesmo estando com a opção de Fundo Vermelho o JavaScript não executa o `onchange`:

**Sem Trigger**

```js
function mostraCampo() {
    var select = document.getElementById('slcTeste');
    var resultado =  document.getElementById('resultado');
    resultado.style.backgroundColor = (select.value == 'vermelho') ?
      "red" :
      "white";
}
```

```css
#resultado{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<select id="slcTeste" onchange="mostraCampo()">
    <option value="vermelho">Fundo Vermelho</option>
    <option value="nenhum">Nenhum</option>
</select>

<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Agora adicionando a linha de códio citada, o browser executa o `onchange` do meu Select assim que o documento é carregado fazendo com que o fundo do Quadrado fique Vermelho

**Com Trigger**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', mostraCampo);


function mostraCampo() {
    var select = document.getElementById('slcTeste');
    var resultado =  document.getElementById('resultado');
    resultado.style.backgroundColor = (select.value == 'vermelho') ?
      "red" :
      "white";
}
```

```css
#resultado{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<select id="slcTeste" onchange="mostraCampo()">
    <option value="vermelho">Fundo Vermelho</option>
    <option value="nenhum">Nenhum</option>
</select>

<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Perfeito Matheus, realmente funcionou, muito obrigado mesmo, ajudou demais!!